# No pagination in Elsevier journals

Tags: publications, elsevier

My paper was accepted in one of Elsevier's journal and it was recently published, but there is no pagination instead they have this "article number" for example "Volume 123, Article No. 212021" similar to those in some Springer and Royal Society journals. The paper is already included in an issue. I am wondering, does my paper officially published or not? Could anyone tell me how this policy is called? or where I can locate this policy in the Elsevier website?

Comment: Why would you care about page numbers?

Comment: My institutions requires page Number before I can get monetary reward

Comment: Perhaps page numbers will be added when it is issued on paper.  Look and see if other papers from a year ago in that journal now have page numbers or not.

Comment: Here is a quick read on this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0143974X19312489?dgcid=raven_sd_via_email

Comment: As @TheGuy notes (and should make an answer?), this is happening more and more. Not unusual in retrospect as few if any of us are paging through physical copies where knowledge of the page number helped finding the article more quickly.

Answer (score 7):

Page numbers are going to go away because (i) stuff isn't actually printed any more, and (ii) page numbers are inconvenient in the publishing process because one needs to know how many pages the articles *before* the current one have before giving the current one page numbers. So the short answer is: You'll need to learn to cope with it.

In similar situations, I've used the following formats to indicate how many pages an article has:

> W. Bangerth: "Stuff more scientists ought to talk about", Journal of Important Research, article 12687 (24 pages), 2019.

or

> W. Bangerth: "Stuff more scientists ought to talk about", Journal of Important Research, vol. 24, pp. 12687/1-24, 2019.

Answer (score 2):

> My paper was accepted in one of Elsevier's journal and it was recently published, but there is no pagination instead they have this "article number" for example "Volume 123, Article No. 212021" similar to those in some Springer and Royal Society journals.

This is not concerning. As others have pointed out, the use of page numbers is outdated and unnecessary, so Elsevier has probably discontinued them for your paper.

> I am wondering, does my paper officially published or not?

Yes it is. By the way, if someone is asking you to provide a page number, maybe you can just put 1 to X where X is the # of pages of your paper? Or put "N/A"? The question is not important so I wouldn't put too much worry into the answer.

Comment: _Physical Review B_, for example -- an example indepedent from Elsevier -- equally does not use _individual_ page numbers, either (e.g., https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.101.115413).  Their bibtex reference then _both_ contains `pages = {115413}` to indicate the start, and `numpages = {12}` to indicate the length in pages of the publication.  Equally, there is an academia.se relevant suggestion here (https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/should-i-cite-a-journals-page-number-or-an-articles).

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need page numbers so that your article can have a sentence or more quoted. Our journal retains them, even though they are a pain. Some journals just number everythign from 1>x, which is a partial solution for quotations.